# Vehicle Physics in the cycles engine?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, physics

I'm attempting to make an animation in which numerous vehicles travel across an uneven plain. In the animation I was hoping to be able to have the suspension of the vehicles simulated as I would in BGE but i have no idea how I would do that in the cycles engine or if it's even possible.

If anyone has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated.

In short what I'm looking for:

Vehicles travel in a straight line over an uneven plain.
Vehicles react to the terrain they're crossing.
Vehicles have some sort of basic suspension.
All done in cycles if at all possible.

Comment: Cycles is a render engine, not a physics engine...  Technically, the BGE is a real-time render engine.  You should be able to apply the same physics concepts (using the physics properties panel), and (I haven't used it much) give it a nudge or apply a constant force?  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Well I know how to do this in BGE however I cant figure out how to here, I've tried some basic stuff with rigid body to try to get what I'm looking for but pretty much all I can get is the vehicle falling and colliding with the surface and remaining in place. I kind of want to find a way of doing it in cycles as I'm doing a lot of stuff with volumetrics in the scene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how to do it in the Game Engine, you're almost done. You can simply play the Game and bake the animation to keyframes while you're at it, reusing the animation later for rendering in Cycles. So after you exit the Game, the keyframes will be baked onto the objects. When you scrub through the timeline, you can see the animation. You can find the **Record Animation** checkbox in the menu here:

[image: Record Animation]

A related question regarding this has been asked here: [Can you bake keyframes in BGE and have them work in cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61335/can-you-bake-keyframes-in-bge-and-have-them-work-in-cycles)

*as a side note, as far as I know this technique has been used in an Open Movie project a while ago. To be more specific, it was the car chase scene of Big Buck Bunny*