# Is it possible to "act" an object's movement?

Tags: animation, scripting

I have no idea whether this has been done or is even feasible. Nonetheless:

The scenario I'm imagining goes like this: you model a spaceship in Blender, add a script so that can control pitch, roll, yaw and throttle using the keyboard, then "perform" the movements that you want to have in your animation. This is then converted into a set of keyframes for location and rotation.

I think this could be a huge time-saver for scenes requiring multiple objects behaving the same way, but I know very little about the practical side. Has anyone else done this? Many thanks.

Comment: I am not sure why this would be a time saver, as opposed to duplicating similar moving objects and slightly changing each? If you did motion capture then you could easily turn gestures into a set of coordinates, but I'm not sure why a keyboard would work in 3d (arrows could do 2d though). Do you have examples of what you have in mind?

Comment: Imagine you had a scene in which you wanted a number of airplanes flying in unique patterns, and each flying as you would expect - turning speed, acceleration, and so on - if you had a flightsim-style setup, you would be able to record yourself piloting each plane.

Comment: This might be what you are looking for -  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61335/can-you-bake-keyframes-in-bge-and-have-them-work-in-cycles